# How to call Multiple CKEditor in one page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I am using **CKEditor** and when i am trying to put another **CKEditor** in the same page then it is not showing..

Comment: `<textarea required="required" rows="6" class="span12 ckeditor m-wrap"  name="sDesc" id="sDesc" style="width: 800px; height:300px;" ></textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
              CKEDITOR.replace( 'sDesc' );
              CKEDITOR.add            
              </script>`





I have tried this and it is working for me like a charm :)

Comment: show your code please

Comment: Thanks Alex, i already resolved and posted as an answer here..

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
              CKEDITOR.replace( 'sDesc' );
              CKEDITOR.add            
              </script>
```

```html
<textarea required="required" rows="6" class="span12 ckeditor m-wrap"  name="sDesc" id="sDesc" style="width: 800px; height:300px;" ></textarea>
```

And

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
              CKEDITOR.replace( 'sDesc2' );
              CKEDITOR.add            
              </script>
```

```html
<textarea required="required" rows="6" class="span12 ckeditor m-wrap"  name="sDesc2" id="sDesc2" style="width: 800px; height:300px;" ></textarea>
```

I have tried above and it is working for me like a charm :)